# sort DataFrame by substrings in rows

Tags: python, regex, pandas, sorting

***Further question: how would I get the mode (ie the most common entry) rather than the minimum? In other words, is there a simple way to replace .min in df['min_year'] = s.unstack(level=-1).min(axis=1) to grab the most common, rather than the smallest number?***

Using Python. I have a DataFrame with three columns:

```
Author | Title | Review
```

Each entry under Review includes multiple years (ie '88 '89 '87). I want to sort by lowest year in each row's cell. Ie, I want all the rows where '87 is the lowest grouped together.

If I do

```
df.index = df['Review'].str.extractall(r'(\'\d\d)')
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1005046 elements, new values have 2449016 elements
```

Ie: my original DataFrame has 1005046 rows, but b/c each row on average has about 2.4 years, I end up with 2449016 extracted years.

The problem seems to be that the function extractall creates a new row for each instance of the pattern, so I end up with 2.449x more rows than I started with.

Here's the output when I call:

```
print(df['Review'].str.extractall(r'(\'\d\d)').head(10))
```

output:

```
               0
    match     
0 0      '69
  1      '69
  2      '69
1 0      '99
  1      '99
2 0      '97
3 0      '86
  1      '86
4 0      '96
6 0      '81
```

Ie: The zero row in the original df had three instances of '69, which creates three separate rows after using extractall. I need to sort each original row by the smallest year, maintaining everything else about the df.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the result of `extractall` to a series:

```
s = df['Review'].str.extractall(r'(\'\d\d)').squeeze()
```

Use the `str` accessor to convert the values to int:

```
s = s.str.replace("'", "").astype(int)
```

Unstack to put extracted values back into rows (with the original index):

```
s.unstack(level=-1)
```

Finally, I wouldn't put the lowest year in an index, but rather a column:

```
df['min_year'] = s.unstack(level=-1).min(axis=1)
df = df.sort_values(by='min_year').drop(['min_year'], axis=1)
```

Comment: The trick is that the years aren't adjacent like that. The rows look like this: Intpr- v49 - Ja '95 - pl03 - [251-500] - TT - v51 - Ap '94 - pl97 - [51-250]

Comment: Oh. Can you show the head of `df['Review'].str.extractall(r'(\'\d\d)')`? First 10 rows maybe.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like this:  0       0      '69
        1      '69
        2      '69
1       0      '99
        1      '99
2       0      '97
3       0      '86
        1      '86

Comment: Except there are three columns: 0 | 0 | '69 is a single column, and so forth. So the extractall function is creating a new row each time there's more than one year in the original row.

Comment: Further question: how would I get the mode (ie the most common entry) rather than the minimum? In other words, is there a simple way to replace .min in df['min_year'] = s.unstack(level=-1).min(axis=1) to grab the most common, rather than the smallest number?

Comment: Can you ask a new question? That would make it easier, thanks.